# SQLAlchemy - manipulate and commit related objects in multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, orm, sqlalchemy

Consider a simple database where table `a` that has one-to-many relationship with tables `b` and `c`, represented in SQLAlchemy.

In my application, at the beginning of code execution I create the `A` object that corresponds to table `a`, and then I'd like to populate table `b` and `c`  by creating and commiting `B` and `C` objects in parallel threads. This is however problematic:

- I should not use same session across multiple threads, since the session is not thread-safe; and even if I tried to, then the following exception is raised: `SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread`
- when I'm using the `scoped_session` to create a new session per thread, since the relationship between `A` and `B`/`C` objects results in `B`/`C` already being assigned to `A`'s session, I'm getting the following exception:
  `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<B at 0x1e68229b780>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')`

What's the desired solution then? Let's pretend I cannot simply wait until both jobs are finished and commit the `A` object with `B` and `C`, altogether.

---

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import object_session
import time
from threading import Thread

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.sqlite', echo=True)
conn = engine.connect()
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

# uncommenting this line shares  a single session across all the threads
# session = session()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b = relationship("B", back_populates="a")
    c = relationship("C", back_populates="a")


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = relationship("A", back_populates="b")
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = relationship("A", back_populates="c")
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


def loop_add_cls(cls):
    def func():
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            session.add(cls(a=a))
            session.commit()
    return func


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

a = A()
session.add(a)
session.commit()

Thread(target=loop_add_cls(B)).start()
Thread(target=loop_add_cls(C)).start()
```

Comment: A solution to the "object is already attached to a session" is to `Session.merge()`: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging.

Comment: This indeed solves the issue, but is this the standard/desired solution, since it involves duplicating the whole object, including its relations?

Comment: At least the last bullet in the examples seems similar to your case, so it's somewhat documented.